# Logitech LUA script adding sleep timer

Tags: lua, scripting, logitech-gaming-software

Was wondering how to add the sleep timer to my LUA script so it doesn't continually loop as fast as possible  and press 0x29, I'd like to make it so when buttons 1 and 3 are pressed on my mouse it hits key 0x29 once every 3-4 seconds instead of as fast as possible.

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" then
        if (arg == 1 or arg == 2) then
            mb1 = IsMouseButtonPressed(1);
            mb2 = IsMouseButtonPressed(3);
            --OutputLogMessage(tostring(mb1) .. " - " .. tostring(mb2));
            if (mb1 == true and mb2 == true) then
                PressAndReleaseKey(0x29);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Your script simulates key 0x29 press only once per physical mouse button press.  It does not `continually loops as fast as possible`.  Actually, you don't have a loop in your code. So, as of now, no sleep timer is required.

Comment: the logitech G hub program I believe automatically loops the script infinitely and as fast as it possibly can which is the problem I have, so I have to physically put something so it only does it once if possible

Comment: `G hub program I believe automatically loops the script infinitely` - No. OnEvent() is invoked once per each physical button press/release. `I have to physically put something` - what does "physically put" mean?

Comment: My apologies I used the wrong word, thank you for your help Egor I fixed my issue by adding a function that presses and releases key within the script. it is now working as intended :)

Comment: Seperate question, @EgorSkriptunoff Is there a way to make it so if I have MouseButtonPressed(1) and (3), within a time frame of 5 seconds to only press and released the key 0x29 once? even if Mousebutton 1 and 3 is released and pressed again within that said time frame of 5 seconds.

Comment: I worded this wrong again sorry, I mean to ask when i invoke OnEvent() to only have it PressAndReleaseKey once every 5 seconds instead of on everytime I invoke event

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current time in milliseconds by `GetRunningTime()`

```
local last_time = -math.huge
local is_pressed = {}

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and (arg == 1 or arg == 2) then
        is_pressed[arg] = false
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and (arg == 1 or arg == 2) then
        is_pressed[arg] = true
        local mb1 = is_pressed[1]
        local mb2 = is_pressed[2]
        --OutputLogMessage(tostring(mb1) .. " - " .. tostring(mb2))
        if mb1 and mb2 and GetRunningTime() - last_time > 5000 then
            PressAndReleaseKey(0x29)
            last_time = GetRunningTime()
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much!! this is awesome, I didnt know you could do that